# How to make boost::log::keywords::file_name use UTC time?

Tags: c++, boost

When using boost::log I can use the following to make the file name use a time stamp as part of the name, but I would really like that time to be in UTC time not local time. How could this be achieved?

```
boost::log::add_file_log(
    boost::log::keywords::file_name = "Log-%Y%m%d-%H00.log",
```

I already know how to make the timestamps within the file_name be UTC, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the file_name UTC.

Thanks in Advance
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use UTC timestamps in file names, unless you want to patch Boost.Log.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

> I would really like that time to be in UTC time not local time

UTC time is "within about 1 second, mean solar time at 0° longitude;" see Wikipedia.

CST (here in Texas) is (essentially) 6 hours different from UTC ... your local time may differ.

Google reports "Coordinated Universal Time is 6 hours ahead of Central Time ".

I think you can compute UTC from local time just by knowing the offset.

My attempt would be:

```
std::string filename;
{  
   std::stringstream ss; 
   ss << "Log-" << year << month << day 
      << "-" << hour << "00.log";
   filename = ss.str();
}
```

and I found this:

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::cout << "UTC:   " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%c %Z");
std::cout << "local: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%c %Z");
```

Combine the two?  GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (with local time)

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::stringstream filename;
filename << "Log-" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%Y%m%d-%H00") << ".log";
boost::log::add_file_log(
    boost::log::keywords::file_name = filename.str(), .....
```